# Python Portfolio Optimizer not generating efficient frontier

Tags: python, optimization, finance

I was hoping to see a clear efficient frontier line, but instead, I am getting a "blob". Am I missing some code that would fix this?

I am looking at 6 different asset classes with daily prices since 2010.

Here is my code:

```
# Yearly returns for individual companies (Should we do yearly?)
df = df.set_index('Date')
ind_er = df.resample('Y').last().pct_change().apply(lambda x: np.log(1+x)).mean() #TODO I changed this code to log, is that correct?
print("")
print(ind_er)
 
# Portfolio returns
w = [0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2]
port_er = (w*ind_er).sum()
print(port_er)
 
# Volatility is given by the annual standard deviation. We multiply by 250 because there are 250 trading days/year.
ann_sd = df.pct_change().apply(lambda x: np.log(1+x)).std().apply(lambda x: x*np.sqrt(250)) #TODO fix number
print(ann_sd)
 
assets = pd.concat([ind_er, ann_sd], axis=1) # Creating a table for visualising returns and volatility of assets
assets.columns = ['Returns', 'Volatility']
print(assets)
 
p_ret = [] # Define an empty array for portfolio returns
p_vol = [] # Define an empty array for portfolio volatility
p_weights = [] # Define an empty array for asset weights
 
num_assets = len(df.columns)
num_portfolios = 10000
 
for portfolio in range(num_portfolios):
    weights = np.random.random(num_assets)
   weights = weights/np.sum(weights)
    p_weights.append(weights)
    returns = np.dot(weights, ind_er) # Returns are the product of individual expected returns of asset and its
                                      # weights
    p_ret.append(returns)
    var = cov_matrix.mul(weights, axis=0).mul(weights, axis=1).sum().sum()# Portfolio Variance
    sd = np.sqrt(var) # Daily standard deviation
    ann_sd = sd*np.sqrt(250) # Annual standard deviation = volatility #TODO is 250 the right number?
    p_vol.append(ann_sd)
 
    data = {'Returns':p_ret, 'Volatility':p_vol}
```

Comment: I would generate optimal portfolios instead of random ones.

Comment: Do you have any resource recommendations to do that?

Comment: Google will find thousands of hits for "mean-variance portfolio optimization". This is a very standard example in finance.